# Not able to see Kate Plugin for Javascript in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, plugins, javascript, kate

I installed Kubuntu 14.04 recently. I had heard about the Javascript related plugins(Pretty JSON specifically)  being there in Kate setup. But it does not show up in any of the options. I am not sure if I need to install that separately. Any help with that regard would be awesome.

Comment: I have the same problem. Can't figure how to get Pretty JSON, on kubuntu 16.10 . Bummer that neither of the answers below are helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to setup kate-plugins including the java-script ones but did not find Pretty JSON anywhere. I even tried asking on the IRC and the mailing list about this but did not find a response. You can however, install and access the plugin as follows:

Open a terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following one line at a time:

```
sudo apt-get install git
sudo apt-get install python-kde4 python-jedi ipython
```

This will install the necessary packages for the plugin. After this, the plugin needs to be cloned from github since it is not available in the ubuntu repositories. For this do the following on the terminal:

```
mkdir build && cd ~/build
git clone https://github.com/goinnn/Kate-plugins
ln -s ~/build/Kate-plugins/kate_plugins/ $(kde4-config --localprefix)/share/apps/kate/pate
```

Now, you can access the plugins in **Settings -> Configure Kate**:

[image: settings menu]

[image: enable plugins]

[image: plugins settings]

Answer (score 0):

In Kate, you can use different "Modes" to affect the highlighting and indentation the way you want it to. Usually, Kate picks this up automatically, but if you need to change it manually, look under Tools > Mode.

[image]

As you can see, there are also options beneath Mode in Tools to affect the highlighting and indentation individually. Using Modes simply sets both the highlighting and indentation to the same thing.