# How do I enable Pâté Python plugin in Kate?

Tags: python, plugins, kate

On Kubuntu 14.04 I'd like to use a Python plugin called Pâté in Kate. It's listed as a plugin there.

[image]

But then it shows an error in the configuration dialogue.
[image]

The help page is not useful at all. Perhaps I have to install some packages (pysmell?), but this is just a guess. How do I get this Python plugin to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you start kate from the terminal, you'll get the exact package you need to install. Open a terminal and type

```
kate
```

and then check what error messages or stack trace it outputs as `ImportError`s and then install the packages. I guest you need to install python-kde4 and python-jedi (just a guess since I had done this long before).

See if

```
 sudo apt-get install python-kde4 python-jedi
```

solves this error. Also check if [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/467833/72576) helps.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how to get the autocompletion to work? I'm getting the error `jedi: Unexpected module's version format.` when hovering over the red colored listed Python Autocompletion plugin.

Comment: @gertvdijk: Did you have a look at this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kate-plugins#autocomplete-python? It is not related to the error it gives, so not sure whether it will solve it.