# how to install kate editor python plugin?

Tags: python, kate

i followed [this link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Kate-plugins#installation) to install python plugin for kate.

in first step it said: "install kate from source. but i couldn't install it from source.(because installing it from source needs qt5(i think) and when i run this line i get dependency error: `sudo apt-get build-dep qtbase5-dev`). after lots of tries couldn't solve that error".

so i skipped this step and installed kate with `apt`.

in third step i followed this steps:

```
cd ~/build
git clone https://github.com/goinnn/Kate-plugins
ln -s ~/build/Kate-plugins/kate_plugins/ $(kde4-config --localprefix)/share/apps/kate/pate
```

since in `apps` folder under `share` directory there wasn't `kate` folder i created `kate` and then `pate` folder under `kate`.

now when i go to `Setting->Configure Kate->Apllications->Plugins` don't see any python option.

my os: `kubuntu 17.04 with KDE Plasma 5.9.4`

my kate version: `16.12.03`

also i tested solutions is this sites but neither did helped me:

- [How do I enable Pâté Python plugin in Kate?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468764/how-do-i-enable-p%C3%A2t%C3%A9-python-plugin-in-kate)
- [Not able to see
  Kate Plugin for Javascript in Kubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456879/not-able-to-see-kate-plugin-for-javascript-in-kubuntu/467833#467833)
- [How to install Kate-plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935343/how-to-install-kate-plugins)